# PyTorch error: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a very simple example

```
import torch

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DEVICE = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    m = torch.nn.Linear(20, 30).to(DEVICE)
    input = torch.randn(128, 20).to(DEVICE)
    output = m(input)
    print('output', output.size())
    exit()
```

and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    output = m(input)
  File "/home/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/speech-reconstruction-7HMT9fTW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/speech-reconstruction-7HMT9fTW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 94, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/speech-reconstruction-7HMT9fTW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1753, in linear
    return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`
```

I'm using `PyTorch 1.7.1`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT. The update of `python -m torch.utils.collect_env` is:

```
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 1.8.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.2
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Clang version: 11.1.0
CMake version: version 3.18.4

Python version: 3.8 (64-bit runtime)
Is CUDA available: True
CUDA runtime version: Could not collect
GPU models and configuration: 
GPU 0: TITAN RTX
GPU 1: TITAN RTX
GPU 2: TITAN RTX
GPU 3: TITAN RTX
GPU 4: TITAN RTX
GPU 5: TITAN RTX
GPU 6: TITAN RTX
GPU 7: TITAN RTX

Nvidia driver version: 460.39
cuDNN version: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7.6.5
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.20.1
[pip3] torch==1.8.0
[pip3] torchaudio==0.8.0
[pip3] torchsummary==1.5.1
[conda] Could not collect
```

Comment: Would you mind to share the output of `python -m torch.utils.collect_env`?

Comment: Added to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in your log, pytorch 1.8 is installed, not 1.7.1. Otherwise please send your log again, using the right python binary.

I faced the exact same issue, using 1.8. Downgrading to 1.7.1 solved it (as mentioned on [huggingface transformers github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10592#issuecomment-792932447)).